# How can I install Message Queuing on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, message-queuing

Setup:

- Windows Server 2003
- Hooked up to a domain

I'd like to install Message Queuing on the server but I get an error message when I try to use the Windows Components Wizards:
The Message Queuing properties of this computer cannot be obtained from Active Directory.

The server doesn't use any domain login information; I have a login that is specific to the server.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing Message Queuing on a domain computer, Message queuing objects are created in AD.  Therefore it requires AD access through an AD user account.  I am sure there is a a work around that doesn't add these to AD I just don't know it.

Comment: From MSDN: "If you are installing Message Queuing on a computer that is a member of a Windows Server 2003 or Windows 2000 domain, you can specify whether the computer will operate in domain mode, by installing the Active Directory Integration subcomponent, or in workgroup mode, by not installing the subcomponent. In the context of Message Queuing, workgroup mode can be defined as any mode of operation that does not allow access to a directory service, even if the applicable computer belongs to a domain."